# Web Scraping Udemy page to get the price of course using python, Beautiful Soup, getting None

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Lines of code are:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

hd = {'Accept-Language': 'en,en-US'}
res = requests.get('https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?q=python%20web%20scraping&src=sac&kw=python%20web%20sc', headers = hd)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
courses = soup.find('div', class_='popper--popper--19faV popper--popper-hover--4YJ5J')
print(courses)
```

I am trying to get the course name from -div class name 'popper--popper--19faV popper--popper-hover--4YJ5J' but getting 'None'

Any suggestion how to get the course name and later the current price? Thank you.

Comment: Printing out your "soup" variable and searching manually, I didn't find a div with that class name. I did find a nav with that class name though. Your bigger problem is that the data you're looking for is added by javascript, so requests will not be able to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with dynamic content so you may try selenium.

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?q=python%20web%20scraping&src=sac&kw=python%20web%20sc"

driver.get(url)
sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
data = []
for course in soup.select('div.course-list--container--3zXPS > div.popper--popper--19faV.popper--popper-hover--4YJ5J'):
    name = course.select_one('div.udlite-focus-visible-target.udlite-heading-md.course-card--course-title--2f7tE').get_text(strip=True)
    price = course.select_one('div.price-text--price-part--Tu6MH.course-card--discount-price--3TaBk.udlite-heading-md span > span').get_text(strip=True).replace('\xa0€','')
    data.append({'name':name,'price':price})
driver.close()

data
```

**Output**

```
[{'name': 'Reguläre Ausdrücke (Regular Expressions) in Python',
  'price': '14,99'},
 {'name': 'Python Bootcamp: Vom Anfänger zum Profi, inkl. Data Science',
  'price': '13,99'},
 {'name': 'WebScraping - Automatisiert Daten sammeln!', 'price': '13,99'},
 {'name': 'Fortgeschrittene Python Programmierung', 'price': '13,99'},
 {'name': 'Python Bootcamp: Der Einstiegskurs', 'price': '14,99'},
 {'name': 'Python - Das Python Grundlagen Bootcamp - Von 0 auf 100!',
  'price': '13,99'},
 {'name': 'Python A-Z - Lerne es schnell & einfach, inkl. Data Science!',
  'price': '13,99'},
 {'name': 'Data Science & Maschinelles Lernen in Python - am Beispiel',
  'price': '13,99'},
 {'name': 'Schnelleinstieg in die Python Programmierung für Anfänger',
  'price': '13,99'},
 {'name': 'Visualisiere Daten mit Python - auch für Anfänger!',
  'price': '18,99'},
 {'name': 'Python-Entwicklung für Einsteiger', 'price': '13,99'},
 {'name': 'Python 3 - Einführung in die Programmierung', 'price': '13,99'},
 {'name': 'Dash - Interaktive Python Visualisierungen für Data Science',
  'price': '21,99'},
 {'name': 'Python für Data Science, Machine Learning & Visualization',
  'price': '13,99'},
 {'name': 'Python in 4 Stunden von Null zum Python Programmierer',
  'price': '13,99'},
 {'name': 'Python 3 programmieren - Einsteigerkurs', 'price': '13,99'},
 {'name': 'Python für Einsteiger, inkl. Data Science', 'price': '13,99'},
 {'name': 'Lambda Funktionen & List Comprehensions in Python',
  'price': '13,99'},
 {'name': 'Deep Learning, Neuronale Netze und TensorFlow 2 in Python',
  'price': '18,99'},
 {'name': 'Python Crashkurs für (Quer) Einsteiger', 'price': '13,99'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will give a try with Selenium.

Comment: Your example code worked like a charm. Thanks @HedgeHog.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the examples from [Beautiful Soup 4 Docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class):

> Remember that a single tag can have multiple values for its “class” attribute. When you search for a tag that matches a certain CSS class, you’re matching against any of its CSS classes

...

> You can also search for the exact string value of the class attribute

When searching for a class and passing in a string, variants of the string will not work. Your code searches for multiple classes on an element and BS4 will try to match an element with exactly those classes. Looking at the HTML in the provided webpage though we see another class `header--gap-button--3bIww`. The presence of this additional class causes BS4 to not find the element.

As another commenter said, it is also a `nav` element, not `div`.

```
# Fails because multiple classes are listed, but the list is not exhaustive (or in order)
courses = soup.find("nav", class_="popper--popper--19faV popper--popper-hover--4YJ5J")

# Works because all classes are listed in order
courses = soup.find("nav", class_="header--gap-button--3bIww popper--popper--19faV popper--popper-hover--4YJ5J",)

# Works because only one class is listed and matched against
courses = soup.find("nav", class_="popper--popper--19faV")
```

Comment: In general good points, but have you tried it once to get the relevant information?  As goalie1998 mentioned it is more a point, that requests would never get the information, cause website is dealing with dynamically loaded content.

Comment: I tried with 'nav' but still didn't go the course search result. Will give a try with Selenium webdriver. Thanks for the inputs.